# Why View Setup Audit Trail doesn't display changes to aura lightning components, applications and events?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, setup, setup-audit-log

Does anyone knows the reason why View Setup Audit Trail doesn't display changes to aura lightning components, applications and events?

Is there any reasons for that or is there any way to make those changes visible in View Setup Audit Trail?

Comment: I would say this is bug of Salesforce. Maybe they are using different mechanism/interface internally to compile apex/vf and lightning components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know that. I believe I have seen that answer somewhere else.
Actually due to [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/admin_monitorsetup.htm), they didn't support display of changes to Lightning components in Setup Audit Trail.

Supported development items are following:
Development

- Apex classes and triggers
- Visualforce pages, custom components, and static resources
- Lightning pages
- Action link templates
- Custom settings
- Custom metadata types and records
- Remote access definitions
- Salesforce Sites settings

  I see [one person has suggested an idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003UIfQAM) but nobody else voted for it - to implement this feature. I think we all should vote for it. Once the feature gets at least 250 votes they would consider it and maybe implement it.

Answer (score -1):

Now you can see the Lightning Component Changes (Kind of a Audit Trail) by going to "Custom Code" > "Lightning Components". Click on each component and you will see Created Date, Last Modified user etc.

[image]

Comment: Consider a situation, Lightning Component is created by Developer A then by Developer B then by Developer C.
How would you know that it has been modified by Developer B?